# How was the Binomial distribution formula derived?

Tags: probability

I'm having a hard time understanding the binomial distribution function. I get that it's used to compute probabilities for binary experiments, but I don't get how they got the formula.
For example, I'm taking a $10$ question true/false quiz. I want to find the probability of getting $7$ of those questions correctly. The sample space should be $2^{10}$, since for the first question question, I have $2$ choices and for each of those $2$ choices, I have another $2$ choices for the second and so on. The number of answer sets that have exactly $7$ questions correct is ${_{10}C_7}$ right?

So the answer should be  ${_{10}C_7}$ divided by $2^{10}$.
Is my reasoning flawed? I didn't need to know the probability of the success(getting a question right) and it's complement. So how did the formula come about. Please help me out

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Your calculation is of the proportion of sample space events that are as desired, which equals the probability of such in the special case $p=\frac12$. As for your question about $\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}$, do you want any old proof of it, or the history behind the first one? If the latter, the [HSM SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) would be a good place for your question.

Comment: Assuming you are always guessing , you have a chance of $\frac{1}{2}$ for every answer to be right. Therefore we have the Laplacian case ,  every of the $2^{10}$ outcomes has the same probability. There are $\binom{10}{7}$ ways where the correctly answered questions are (this is by the way equal to $\binom{10}{3}=\frac{10\cdot 9\cdot 8}{3\cdot 2}$ ). The quotient is the probability for exactly $7$ correct answers. Also study the binomial distribution (here with paramters $10$ and $1/2$) for more details.

Comment: @J.G.  Thank you. You talked about the special case of p= 1/2. Does the calculation change when p ≠ 1/2. If so, how would it? And as for the formula, any old proof would do please.

Answer (score 0):

There are 10 questions. You have to get exactly 7 right. In how many ways can that happen? $^{10}C_7$. There's only 1 way to get all 3 of the remaining 3 answers wrong.

So the number of ways to get exactly 7 answers right = $^{10}C_7 \times 1 = ^{10}C_7$

How many possible combinations of right and wrong answers are there? $2^{10}$

The probability you're looking for =$\frac{^{10}C_7}{2^{10}}$

If $r$ = right and $w$ = wrong, you're looking for the coefficient of $r^7w^3$ in the binomial expansion of $(r + w)^{10}$

... I think.

Comment: Alright, thnx. But how does this relate to the binomial pdf?

Comment: I don't see a pdf mon ami.